# In Objective C, how to override an application delegate function from a static Cocoa Touch Library class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, air

I'm creating an Adobe ANE ( AIR Native Extension ) for iOS to enable me show a confirmation alert when AdMob tries to open a link on the device browser ( Safari ).
What I've reached is that the following function is the one to override from the application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

But nothing happened when I implemented this function in my static Cocoa Touch Library class.

So I wonder what is the right way to make this overriding.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: This function have to be implemented in your AppDelegate file, not in your library.

Comment: As far as I know I've no access to the AppDelegate as I'm creating the mentioned library to be an extension to a Flash application.

If you have any knowledge about Flash, AIR, or ANE, can you tell me if it's possible to access the AppDelegate through any?